# How to transfer all public files on one skydrive account to another?

Tags: file-transfer, cloud-storage, onedrive

How do you transfer all public files on one skydrive account to another?

I have some files that I have made public and my friends wants to transfer/copy those files to his account without downloading it.

Comment: Can you create download links in Skydrive?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

*Please be informed that if you want to transfer files from one SkyDrive account to another, you have to manually save them to your computer first then add/upload them to the other one.*

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/skydrive-files/how-to-transfer-content-from-one-account-to/58885797-15c2-4d61-b1c3-2883d64bfb9b?msgId=05dfcd50-3160-4bcc-ada9-ea2e7249f761)

Comment: lame isn't it? let's say i want to share the picture with my gf, but she can own the pictures on her skydrive folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can.

With an external service, i've found services that can transfer files from different cloud platforms.
Examples: multcloud and cloudfuze.

I tested multcloud, transfered 3Gb of files and it did it, took awhile but it was faster than redownload all to my pc and reupload it.